# Saving / Retrieving DBGrid column settings: Columns.LoadFromStream and Columns.SaveToStream

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I am actually after some ideas to how to address my problem below:

I have TCRTBGrid that users can move columns around and change the width. I want to save the setting in a database. I guess I can do this bit by using

`Columns.LoadFromStream and Columns.SaveToStream`
then store data in a blob field - Q: Can I store in a longtext field ?

but the biggest problem is that if new columns were added during design time after saving the column settings i want to append these new columns to the end.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Add DefaultStream into the database. then compare the user stream and de default stream. If there is an new or deleted column then take action.

Comment: @Ravaut123, this will not be useful because if you change the order or columns position the stream will change, even though you did not *add* any new columns.

Comment: @kobik: Nice but why not usefull. I just make an example on my pc and it works like a charme. Load the default stream to a default grid (this is unvisible). Load de using grid. Then compare the columns of the default grid with the using grid. All the columns that are in the default grid but not in the using grid add it to the using grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what Ravaut123 suggested and worked !!!!!! 
Once retrieved the user setting , compared it with design grid manually for new and deleted fields 'cause that is only way I could think of.

Anyway thank you to both Ravaut123 and  kobik.

Comment: any sample code?